¿como lograr que el navegador no se cierre con la automatizacion de Selenium?
Que tal dev estoy intentando hacer un pequeña auotomatizacion con python y selenium estoy practicando enviar datos por teclado pero al terminar de enviar los datos en la pagina el navegador se me cierra automaticamente sin tener tener el codigo de driver.quit(), quiesera la saber como mantener el navegador abierto siempre y que lo yo pueda cerrar manualmente.
Les dejo un pequeño ejemplo con netflix el cual envia el cual envia usuario y contraseña y se cierra el navegador.
  from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import time
    
    # Ruta al ejecutable de msedgedriver
    service = Service(r"C:\Edge\msedgedriver.exe")
    
    # Inicializar el navegador Edge
    driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)
    driver.get("https://www.netflix.com/login")
    
    # Encontrar el campo de usuario y enviar el correo electrónico
    usuario = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "userLoginId")
    usuario.send_keys("algunusario@gmail.com")
    
    # Encontrar el campo de contraseña y enviar la contraseña
    clave = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
    clave.send_keys("asdasdfasdf")
    
    # Enviar la tecla ENTER al campo de contraseña
    clave.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


No uso edge, pero prueba con: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425419/how-to-make-sure-selenium-does-not-close-the-browser. Es para Chrome, pero puedes adaptarlo:from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
